# A program in c thats prints rectangle with x and y of * pattern

Tags: c, loops, rectangles

i am trying to make a program that prints rectangle of x and y of * , lets say i have x= 7 , y = 4 , so it will print:

[image]

when i check that code  with the bot that checks if my code is correct(for school homework) , it give me that my code is incorrect although i have the same output , after i asked some of my classmates and the teachers it turned out  that  the last line of the code must be the line where it is printf("") and not printf("\n") (the bot thinks that the last line of code where it is printf("\n") some kind of error or something) , so how i can get the same result with my current code but , wheres  the last line of code is printf("*") and not printf("\n") ?  i need my last line of code to be printf("*") and not printf("\n") and still get the same result , any suggestions ? basically i cant just remove the last printf("\n") because it will change the output , so i need to put it in somewhere else with an if statement or something so it will give me the same results

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS


int main() {
    int i, j, rows, columns;
    scanf_s("%d", &rows);
    scanf_s("%d", &columns);
    for (i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= rows; j++)
        {   
            if(i == 1 || i == columns || j == 1 || j == rows)
                printf("*");
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");

    }


}
```

Comment: You can't remove it, but you can make it conditional. But another possible reason for failing is that `rows` is the inner loop, when it should be the outer one.

Comment: I would argue that printing the `"\n"` at the end of each line (as you have done) is more correct.

Comment: ...when I enter 4 rows and 7 columns, I don't get that picture. I get a tall thin one. Looking at your console, you entered 7 rows and 4 columns ;)

Comment: The names of your `rows` and `columns` variables are confusing though. I would have made `rows` the number of lines and `columns` the number of characters on each line. (Or perhaps the names are correct and your interpretation of the desired shape is incorrect.)

Comment: @WeatherVane how i can make it conditional ? and about the rows , no its correct , when u enter 4 rows and 7 columns  u get a tall one , it doesn't matter as i got the output that i needed , now i need to solve the problem that the printf("\n") must not be in the last , what ur suggestion ?

Comment: Well, what was the specification for entering the rows and columns? Which comes first? You don't mention that. What does the **bot** enter for rows and columns? As for the conditional, which "row" do you want to skip the newline? Make that the condition, but first get the rows/columns right.

Comment: @WeatherVane will in the question its asked to get value of x first then y , where it is x for length and y for width  so rows for x and y for columns

Comment: So it's the variable names which are confusing. So `if(column != XXX) ...`

Comment: @WeatherVane well how i can change my program so it will be correct as they ask ? i need x for length and y for width , if simply replace the rows and columns with x and y it will be correct ? becuase if i do the opposite and type 7 for x and 4 for y i dont get the output they asking for..